# Laravel 4 - elegant way to display a collection part by part using BLADE

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-blade

I have this simple task:
displaying rulers of several Chinese dynasties, but in several separate places of my VIEW file.

In my controller I create variable

```
$dynasties = Dynasty::get()
```

In my **Dynasty** model I declared a relation to **Ruler** model named **rulerName**

Now in my VIEW, for each dynasty I have a brief intro and then I do this:

Rulers:

```
@if($now_rulers_of_this_dynasty = 1) 
@endif  // dynasty id written as number; hack: this way the variable is not printed

@foreach($dynasty->rulerName as $dynasty_ruler)

     @if($dynasty_ruler->dynasty_id == $now_rulers_of_this_dynasty )
        {{$dynasty_ruler->name}}
     @endif
@endforeach
```

**My problem:** 
Is there any elegant way to do this in L4's BLADE? 
How I can print only a part of a collection?

**The code above does the job, but I look for a more elegant way to achieve the same result.**

Edit: This is what I have: about 40 dynasties and ancient states, and c. 300 rulers, several per a dynasty.
My goal: I want to grab all the rulers from the database into a single variable (collection), and list them in my view file. But not all of them at once. I want them in many places - rulers of the Dynaxty X, then Dynasty Y - printed by another foreach loop.

Comment: `->dynasty_id` is the same for all related `dynastyRulers` so you definitely don't know what you want to achieve. Or at least can't phrase it clearly.

Comment: dynasty_id changes, as the 300 rulers belong to many different dynasties. I am unable to put it more clearly.

Comment: Of course it changes, but not here in your code: `foreach dynasty->ruler` returns only `rulers` with the same `dynasty_id`.

Comment: Jarek, this discussion leads to nowhere. As you clearly see I wish to know if there is a method of filtering the collection in BLADE without extra IF inside the FOREACH.
Here [dayleress](http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-collections) - secion on FILTER() function. the method is presented, but it forces me to create a new variable for each dynasty, and then pass the new variables to VIEW. It's not elegant in my opinion.

Comment: You didn't get my point. You either want something that is not presented in the code you pasted, or you don't understand my suggestion. So, having collection of `dynasties` with related collections of `rulers` there is no reason to create or filter anything, because calling pseudo `foreach dynasties { dynasty->rulers }` will return only rulers of given dynasty. And if you then wish to further filter dynasty's rulers by anything else, then of course some logic would be necessary (`if` or anything else depending on your needs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming some things here, since you haven't shared your models with us...
First, your relationship should probably be called `rulers` instead of `rulerName`. I'm gonna use `rulers` in the example code that follows.

Also I'm not totally sure I understood your problem right, since it seems pretty easy to me, so just correct me if I'm wrong. Anyways here's how I would do it:

```
@foreach($dynasties as $dynasty)
    <p>{{ $dynasty->intro }}</p>
    <ul>
    @foreach($dynasty->rulers as $ruler)
        <li>{{ $ruler->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of the answer

Comment: I cannot vote up as my reputation is not high enough, sorry for that! Will do that later

Comment: I noticed that, but right below the vote counts there is a big checkmark, that will mark this answer as accepted. [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) should help ;)